# How do I request an issue to be moved to the paid issue queue when I did not create the issue?

Tags: civicase

I'm wanting to move this issue to the paid issue queue from gitlab.

I'm not exactly sure what the steps are since I have not started the issue.

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1400

Are only users who have created an issue allowed to move it to the paid issue queue?

Do I need to recreate this as a new issue?

Comment: Hi Phillip - i had jitendra take a look so I can send through an estimate if you wish.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion 
Hi Pete, could you please send that through. Thank you!

Comment: sure. sent through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this link it says send an email to info@civicrm.org: https://civicrm.org/about/core-team

It also says you can hire any of the experts.

On the particular civicase issue there are a couple tangled up issues with closed cases (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1401) but maybe this one (which is listed in there) could be dealt with without getting too tangled. I have it on my own todo list to someday look closer at the proposal referenced in there about the more general issue, which may or may not intersect with this one.